# generalized copy constructor in an inner class

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to specify a conversion from `A<T>::B` to `A<U>::B`.

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        B() {}

        template<typename U>
        B(const typename A<U>::B& rhs) {}
    };
};

int main()
{
    A<int>::B x;
    A<double>::B y = x;
}
```

I thought this would do it, but I get the compiler error:

> conversion from ‘A<int>::B’ to non-scalar type ‘A<double>::B’ requested"

Why isn't my code correct, and what's the correct way to achieve the desired conversion?

Comment: For clarification, what is the desired conversion? Because you aren't converting an int to a double, but an A<int>::B to an A<double>::B, which is a class to another class.

Comment: @SSight3: let me guess Robert is trying to reimplement smart pointers with external refcounts and polymorphic assignments...

Comment: The conversion is from A<T>::B to A<U>::B for any T,U. int and double are just the examples I used.  And no, sehe, that's not what I'm doing.

Comment: @Robert: well, anyway the compiler is unable to infer the template parameters. If I understood the standard well enough to explain _why_, I'd have answered it by now :)

Comment: Is there any reason why B should be an inner class of A? If you were to refactor B to be a class of its own you would have a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly amended source, to demonstrate that this is about the limits to the type deduction system:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        B() {}

        template<typename U>
            B(const typename A<U>::B& rhs) {}

        template<typename U>
            B& operator=(const typename A<U>::B& rhs) {}

        template<typename U>
            B& something(const typename A<U>::B& rhs) {}
    };
};

int main()
{
    A<int>::B x;

    A<double>::B y(x);     // fails to deduce
    A<double>::B y = x;    // fails to deduce
    A<double>::B y; y = x; // fails to deduce

    x.something(y);        // fails to deduce
    x.something<double>(y);// NO PROBLEM
}
```

You see that when we help the compiler a little, there is no more problem. Also note the actual compiler error (gcc) shows it's confusion:

```
test.cpp|24 col 15| note: candidate is:
test.cpp|15 col 44| note: template<class U> A<T>::B& A<T>::B::something(const typename A<U>::B&) 
 [with U = U, T = int, A<T>::B = A<int>::B, typename A<U>::B = A<T>::B]
```

Notice the part where `U = U` (i.e. unresolved)

Answer (score 4):

A template cannot be a copy constructor. §12.8/2, footnote:

> Because a template constructor is never a copy constructor, the presence of such a template does not suppress the implicit declaration of a copy constructor. Template constructors participate in overload resolution with other constructors, including copy constructors, and a template constructor may be used to copy an object if it provides a better match than other constructors.

Since your template's argument is `const &`, its signature will be exactly the same as the implicitly-declared function in the copying case, so it will never be used as a copy constructor.

That may be OK, because in the example you are using it as a *conversion* constructor. However, template arguments before a `::` are a non-deduced context, so the compiler cannot plug in `A<int>::B` and resolve `int`. Because of the various ways of specializing templates, there is no way for the compiler to figure out which `A`, if any, qualifies. You could add `typedef A<int>::B B;` inside `A<float>`, and then both `int` and `float` would qualify as `U`.

You can fix this by using SFINAE and adding member types to the classes to help navigate the hierarchy. Here is a [demo.](http://ideone.com/NogE0)

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    typedef T type;

    struct B
    {
        B() {}

        template<typename U>
        B(const U& rhs, typename U::nest_A_parent * = NULL ) {
            std::cout << "copied from type "
            << typeid( typename U::nest_A_parent::type ).name() << '\n';
        }

    private:
        typedef A nest_A_parent;
        template< typename U >
        friend struct B;
    };
};

int main()
{
    A<int>::B x;
    A<double>::B y( x );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How to do a *conversion* constructor (as Potatoswatter pointed out, it can't be a copy constructor by definition) that only matches the nested type `B`, for any `A<T>::B`:

```
namespace detail {

// private type to identify all A<T>::B
struct B {};

} // detail

// trait to identify all A<T>::B
// a template alias could also be used here
template<typename T>
struct is_b: std::is_base_of<detail::B, T> {};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    struct B: detail::B {
        B() {}

        template<typename U>
        B(U&& u)
        {
            static_assert( is_b<typename std::decay<U>::type>::value
                           , "Conversion only allowed from A<T>::B" );
        }
    };
};
```

This technique has the advantage that it's not using SFINAE so an invalid conversion attempt will be reported via `static_assert` instead of failing silently. On the other hand, you'll need SFINAE if there is at least one other template conversion constructor.

This is assuming that `A<T>::B` will differ from `A<U>::B` (for different `T` and `U`). If the nested types are identical (as it is the case in your simplified, example code) you'd be better served by defining `B` somewhere else and using a `typedef some_private_namespace::B B;` in `A`.